# Cordova iOS app on keyboard ON header n fixed div moves up

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova

I am creating an iOS app where i have fixed position header and div. Know when keyboard comes up the fixed position header and div also moves up and not visible to user unless scroll down. I want the header and fixed position div to remain fixed and the contain with input fields moves up when keyboard in ON.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.